# python: how to get result from a call functions in real time?

Tags: python, multithreading, call

What I want to do is get result from call functions in real time.
For example, I want to get the result of `i` in class model in real time.However, if I use return,I can only get the result of `i` once.

```
import threading

class model(object):
    """docstring for model"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def func(self):  
        for i in range(1000):
            print('i',i)
            return i

class WorkThread(threading.Thread):  
    # trigger = pyqtSignal()  
    def __int__(self):  
        super(WorkThread,self).__init__()  

    def run(self):  
        model1=model()
        result = model1.func() #I want to get `i` from class model in real time,however return can only get once.
        print('result',result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkThread=WorkThread()
    WorkThread.start()
    for j in range(1000,2000):
        print('j',j)
```

Anyone has a good idea? Hopefully for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options; you could:

- Use a generator function, to produce the results as you iterate. This requires that the `model1.func()` call loops over the generator returned by the `model1.func()` call. Use this if you don't need access to the data from another thread.
- Use a queue; push `i` results into the queue as you produce them, and another thread can receive them from the queue.